# cordova build android -- release not loading files

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, oracle-jet

[image]I'm trying to build android apk in release type but when run on android device it just show white screen.
so I served release type on browser to check then I found there are lot of missing files all libs are not there

debug type works fine on mobile and browser.

Comment: what ionic version are you using? and what command are you using to build your apk?

Comment: which ionic version it is .. and show us html code .. what path you have used so far for this

Comment: I'm using oracle jet

Comment: even when I generate apk it works fine in debug mode but  in release mode it just show white screen on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was some missing files in main-release-paths.json
everything works fine after defined missing paths